# adding hours depending if date in DST

Tags: python, python-3.x

From external API I'm getting this date as string `'2021-03-31 21:00:00'`. API returns it as UTC.

The goal is to add in summer 2 hours and in winter 3 hours.

1.

Is there some library that solves this problem?

2. if not, then I should probably calculate myself if today is a day in DST and add 3 hours and if not add 2? if so how can i do it

Comment: Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a correct answer.

Comment: @itprorh66 unfortunately i have no one else to ask :(

Comment: For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pytz` for it if it is for a timezone with daylight savings which I'm assuming it is:

```
import datetime
import pytz


def convert_timezone(time_string: str, timezone_string: str):
    return pytz.UTC.localize(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(
            time_string,
            '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
        )).astimezone(pytz.timezone(timezone_string))


# Non Daylight saving
print(convert_timezone('2021-02-28 21:00:00', 'utc'))
print(convert_timezone('2021-02-28 21:00:00', 'Europe/London'))
print(convert_timezone('2021-02-28 21:00:00', 'Europe/Paris'))
# Daylight saving
print(convert_timezone('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 'utc'))
print(convert_timezone('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 'Europe/London'))
print(convert_timezone('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 'Europe/Paris'))
# Dont-use daylight saving
print(convert_timezone('2021-02-28 21:00:00', 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'))
print(convert_timezone('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 'Atlantic/Cape_Verde'))
```

outputs:

```
2021-02-28 21:00:00+00:00
2021-02-28 21:00:00+00:00
2021-02-28 22:00:00+01:00
2021-07-31 21:00:00+00:00
2021-07-31 22:00:00+01:00
2021-07-31 23:00:00+02:00
2021-02-28 20:00:00-01:00
2021-07-31 20:00:00-01:00
```

Just use it with your timezone and treat the return value as you would any `datetime.datetime` object. e.g.

```
print(convert_timezone('2021-07-31 21:00:00', 'Europe/Paris').strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M"))
```

outputs as a string:

```
07/31/2021, 23:00
```